# How to remove your name from the title bar of Microsoft Office apps?

Tags: microsoft-office, privacy

Microsoft Office apps display your Microsoft Account name in the title bar:

[image]

How to hide/edit/remove it?

People were asking this since showing the name was introduced into Office, and have even come up with a solution that needs you to edit the registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities\..._LiveId` / `FriendlyName`), but it doesn't work since about 2023 (see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/2023-removehide-name-from-office-bar/18761b66-7219-4f93-ad33-6fc73556d11c)).

<sup>Note, that Outlook is an exception. It displays only the account picture, but not the name.</sup>

Comment: I don't think this is possible any more.

Comment: change your login to something other than your name